# how to development Android app with only one device for multi device screen size

Tags: android

I am start to developing android app.

Please teach me any resource or tips which how to develop android app for multidevice.
Android , there is so many device sizes. It makes me confuse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Check the link, It help you 

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534454/how-to-design-application-to-support-multi-screen-devices-and-tablets-in-android

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great tutorial at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html that sets out best practices for layout design. Also look into building your application around fragments to support multiple pages on larger devices using http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Finally, if you only have one device, you can use the emulator to test different screen resolutions and make sure it still works as intended.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using eclipse;

In the visual editor for the layouts, search for the configuration button which is right next to the 'palette'. Select 'preview all screen sizes', therefore you can see your layout in all possible screen sizes. However this only helps you to see the layouts, in order to see the functions in action, create virtual devices and test your apps.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following steps:

1.) **Make it supportable for all screens.**

Paste the below code in `<manifest>` tag but above of your `<application>` tag.

Code::

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

2.) **Set your all required sdk targets, example below:**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="16"
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

3.) **Add the following folders in `res/` and develop layouts for each of them**

```
a. layout
b. layout-land
c. layout-small
d. layout-small-land
e. layout-large
f. layout-large-land
g. layout-xlarge
h. layout-xlarge-land
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks,
Harpreet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create instances of avd with different sizes and densities for testing all kind of screens.

In eclipse:

- Click in Window/Android Virtual Device Manager;
- New
- Device -> Here you can select screen size and pixel density