# Designing for overall Android devices

Tags: java, android, layout

I had developed an application for 7 inch tablets. The design was fitting correctly to celkon,Bril Slates but the same design is not fitting into Samsung galaxy tab(7 inch).I was wired, after seeing these differences between same 7inch tablets.

May i know why this happens? Then how difficult, if i develop an application that supports every screen.

This didnt help me out to solve the issue
[How to design application to support multi-screen devices and tablets in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534454/how-to-design-application-to-support-multi-screen-devices-and-tablets-in-android).
Can any one guide me/suggest any links to develop an application that supports every android devices

Comment: have you gone through this link - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Instead of downvoting my question it would be more helpful if u guide me why there is differences between these same inch tablets

Answer (score 1):

That is not an easy thing as you need to make layouts and images not only for different sizes, but for different DPI too. Thus consider looking at every device you want to publish at parameters. Usually you have to do pretty much work to make an app looking good on all resolutions, DPI and Android versions.

Comment: So we need to check for density and layout size too?

Comment: @Kalai.G actually you should consider looking at width in `dp` of the device so as you can abjust for different pairs resolutuion/DPI. Read the article http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Comment: thanks maxim. So we need to create a folder like res/layout and       
res/layout-w600dp. So if i am creating an layout programmatically and setting width to an edit text to 50 dip means it will fit correct to small size and looks too small for tablets na?

Comment: @Kalai.G yes, you do need exactly this.

Comment: How to overcome that issue when i use code to design? i need to create folder for res/values????

Comment: @Kalai.G yes you neede to crate multiply folders for different devices. Try to extract all device-dependent values, images and layouts with as small volume as you can. It helps you not to rewrite a complite design. In code you just refer to R.something and Android would give you the proper file on every device.

Answer (score 1):

though the size is same...the resolution and form factor differ for each devices...its not appropriate to just the screen size alone..devices picks up their layouts and drawables from specific folders...for instance nexus7 will pick uo the drawables and layouts from tvdpi folder...so you need to understand which devices your app will be supporting and create proper layouts for them..this is in fact an overhead for the developers and  considered as a drawback in android development.

Comment: Okay,it would be better if u provide a link that you are following for development. Is my question really needs to be downvoted?

Comment: I am not sure why you question is downvoted. May be your question is downvoted just because you have not found similar questions already exists in stackoverflow.and people have provided answers for that. You should go through those answers first and then post your question if you dont find an answer there. I had the same issues 2 years back. refer this link for detailed info
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Best to read is the android guide on how to achieve this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

About your problem with one tablet vs the other it can be also a matter of density combined with screen size. From the link about you will understand how to combine the sizes

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

with various densities: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi ...

Comment: So we need to check for density and device size too?

Comment: you have this folders in the res/ and inside you add the layout and graphics. You can have only one layout for all the devices but different images for different resolution or only one in draw folder which will be scaled. Please read at the link from Android, I can't explain it better and more comprehensive than there